# Intel TBB parallel_reduce returning incorrect result

Tags: c++, parallel-processing, intel, tbb

I am trying to use Intel TBB parallel_reduce to compute the best response to a user move in a Connect 4 game. I wrote a simple function that when passed a column number returns a heuristic score corresponding to the utility of playing that move. My intent is to call this function in parallel and then return the reduction of the returned results. The reduction will be the move with the highest heuristic score.

However I find that I get inconsistent results. I expect the move for column 0 to be returned from the parallel reduce (as I have written the heuristic score function such that it returns 7 - column number as the score).

I have attached the C++ code. Here is a sample output that it produces:

> Return move 0
>
> Return move 1
>
> Return move 2
>
> Return move 6
>
> Return move 4
>
> Return move 5
>
> Compare moves 5Return move 3 & 6
>
> Compare moves 3 & 4
>
> Compare moves 3 & 5
>
> Compare moves 2 & 3
>
> Best move is 2

I have looked at the code many many times and am at loss to understand why it does not always return 0 as the best move. It sometimes does return zero, but not always. As you can see above, move 0 is evaluated, but the reduction lambda function never gets it as an input. Any help will be greatly appreciated. I have a vague suspicion that the identity of 0 that I have used, may not be right. However I'm not sure what it should be.

```
#include <tbb\blocked_range.h>
#include <tbb\parallel_reduce.h>

#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int getMoveHueristicScore(int columnCounter) {

    int returnValue = 7 - columnCounter;
    return returnValue;
}

int bestHeuristicScore(int numberOfColumns) {

    std::vector<int> moveScores(numberOfColumns, -1 * INT_MAX);

    return tbb::parallel_reduce(
        tbb::blocked_range<int>(0, numberOfColumns),
        0,
        [=, &moveScores](const tbb::blocked_range<int>& range, int bestMove)->int {
        int bestScore = -1 * INT_MAX;
        for (int columnCounter = range.begin(); columnCounter != range.end(); ++columnCounter) {
            moveScores.at(columnCounter) = getMoveHueristicScore(columnCounter);
            if (moveScores.at(columnCounter) > bestScore) {
                bestScore = moveScores.at(columnCounter);
                bestMove = columnCounter;
            }
        }
        std::cout << "Return move " << bestMove << std::endl;
        return bestMove;
    },
        [=, &moveScores](int bestMove1, int bestMove2)->int {
        std::cout << "Compare moves " << bestMove1 << " & " << bestMove2 << std::endl;
        if (moveScores.at(bestMove1) > moveScores.at(bestMove2)) {
            return bestMove1;
        }
        else {
            return bestMove2;
        }
    }
    );
}

int main() {

    int bestMove = bestHeuristicScore(7);
    std::cout << "Best move is " << bestMove << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

There's no problem with `tbb::parallel_reduce` in this case. The problem is that your code is ignoring the `init` parameter to the `func` function.

TBB has different options for how to perform the reduction.  It can choose to call `func` for different subranges in different threads and then combine the results using the `reduction` function; it can call `func` multiple times in the same thread, each time passing in the result of the previous invocation; or it can use a combination of both tactics.

Looking at your implementation of `func`:

```
[=, &moveScores](const tbb::blocked_range<int>& range, int bestMove)->int {
    int bestScore = -1 * INT_MAX;
    for (int columnCounter = range.begin(); columnCounter != range.end(); ++columnCounter) {
        moveScores.at(columnCounter) = getMoveHueristicScore(columnCounter);
        if (moveScores.at(columnCounter) > bestScore) {
            bestScore = moveScores.at(columnCounter);
            bestMove = columnCounter;
        }
    }
    std::cout << "Return move " << bestMove << std::endl;
    return bestMove;
}
```

The `init` parameter `bestMove` is never used; instead, a value `bestScore` is initialized to some dummy value.  TBB may call `func` multiple times, each time passing in the computed `bestMove` from the previous call, but this is ignored and therefore the final result will be the `bestMove` from whatever subrange happened to be passed to the last call.

The fix is to use `bestMove` to initialize best score, as follows:

```
int bestScore = moveScores.at(bestMove);
```

Then TBB will carry the running best score from one invocation of `func` to the next, ensuring that the final result is indeed the global best score.

Comment: Haven't got around to checking. Will check this week. Have been tied up with other stuff.

Comment: I tried this and it crashed. On taking a closer look, I'm not sure if the explanation makes sense to me. The change suggested was to the Map part of parallel reduce. I was under the impression that outputs from all the map parts are given to the reduce function (the second lambda) and not to another thread running a map part. Maybe my understanding of TBB is wrong. I'm not sure what to do now.

Comment: `func` is not really a map, it's a reduction of a subrange starting with `initial_value`.  The second function `reduction` can be used to join the results of subranges computed by different workers. `func` may be used to accumulate multiple subranges computed by a single worker, so it's important that it starts with the provided initial value, rather than with the identity value.
https://software.intel.com/en-us/node/506063

Answer (score 0):

You claimed that the left identity for your reduction is `0`, which is clearly not the case.  You must provide such an identity, and handle it in your reducer.  Try `-1` and explicitly handle it.

And `-INT_MAX` is off by 1.

And capture explicitly when you run into bugs (remove the `=`).  Knowing what is captured sometimes helps a lot.

I am surprised your sample output lacks a mention of `1` in reduction, but I am not surprised by the lack of `0`.

Comment: Thanks @Yakk. I rectified the problem with -1 * INT_MAX by filling the vector with -1 instead. I changed the identity to -1 and updated the reducer to return the other parameter if any parameter is -1. I also removed the "=" to capture explicitly. It did not help though. I'm still getting inconsistent results.

Return move 0  
Return move 1  
Return move 2  
Return move 6  
Return move 4  
Return move 3  
Compare moves 3 & 4  
Return move 5  
Compare moves 5 & 6  
Compare moves 3 & 5  
Compare moves 2 & 3  
Best move is 2

Comment: @AggieMan so, I googled tbb parallel_reduce bug and got disturbing hits from only a few years ago of some bad bugs (hanging, failure to clean up, etc).  Maybe the code is ... just buggy?  There are two overloads, the other one looks older (as it predates lambda), possibly trying to use the older one might get less bugs?

Comment: Thanks @Yakk. That's unfortunate. Maybe Intel will clean this up soon. I have a workaround for the Map-Reduce and use a Map (parallel_for) followed by a for loop to do the Reduce part. That works. I'll try the other parallel_for to see if that works.

Comment: There's no bug in `parallel_reduce` (in this case) - see [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32907606/2293756).

Answer (score 0):

You're accessing a `std::vector` from multiple threads, which is not safe. This may be the source of your problem. Change your `moveScores` container to be `tbb::concurrent_vector<int>`.

Comment: Each thread will get independent ranges for the vector index. So it should not be a problem. The vector does not resize as that would cause a problem if it did. I'll try using the concurrent vector to see if it helps. Thanks!!!

Comment: I tried concurrent_vector but got the same results as with std::vector.